# Fetch category id's through sql in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, category, magento2.3, category-attribute

I want to get the list of category id's with category name through sql. how can i do that?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: @Black nothing for now

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SET @NAME_ATTR_ID = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code='name' AND entity_type_id=3);

SELECT
  cce.entity_id
FROM
  catalog_category_entity cce
JOIN
  catalog_category_entity_varchar ccev
ON
  ccev.row_id=cce.row_id
  AND ccev.attribute_id=@NAME_ATTR_ID
  #AND ccev.store_id=0 
  AND ccev.value LIKE '%gear%'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity` LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar ON catalog_category_entity.entity_id = catalog_category_entity_varchar.entity_id WHERE catalog_category_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 45
```

Thanks

Comment: cool, this worked, how can i get this into csv . i am running this query through command line

Answer (score 1):

It fetch all the category Ids, their names, url key and their parent id

```
SELECT DISTINCT cc.entity_id as category_id, cc.value as title, cc1.value as 
urlkey ,cce.parent_id as parent_id ,0 as top,level as `column`,position as 
sort_order,1 as status,created_at as date_added,updated_at as date_modified 

FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar cc 
JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cc1 ON cc.entity_id=cc1.entity_id   
JOIN catalog_category_entity_int cc_int ON cc1.entity_id=cc_int.entity_id 
join eav_attribute as att on att.`attribute_id` = cc.`attribute_id`
JOIN eav_entity_type ee ON att.entity_type_id=ee.entity_type_id JOIN catalog_category_entity cce ON cc.entity_id=cce.entity_id 
WHERE cc.attribute_id in (select distinct attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code ='name')
   AND cc1.attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code ='url_path')
and cc_int.attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code ='is_active')
and cc_int.value = 1
and ((cce.parent_id = 2 and cce.children_count > 1) or cce.parent_id > 2)       
#AND ee.entity_model = 'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category'
order by cce.parent_id asc, 
cce.position asc;
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: getting this error Unknown column 'cc.Row_id' in 'field list'

Comment: @Nafisa it is working at my end. I tested this query as well. Maybe you have case sensitive issue `cc.Row_id` to `cc.row_id` so I update my query for you.

Comment: same error Unknown column 'cc.row_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Ok I got it. It's version issue. I am using magento enterprise 2.2.5. I just replace the `row_id` with `entity_id`.Now it will work for you as well. Check my updated query